# Identify grammatical subject of type of a verb in sentence using wordnet?

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy, wordnet

Is there a way to identify grammatical subject of type of verb in a sentence. For example

he drinks pepsi.

In above sentence the verb drink normally requires a grammatical subject of type ANIMATE and a grammatical object of type LIQUID (pepsi).

Is there any features in wordnet or NLTK to check what type of a subject or object a verb expect in sentence?